# Spring WebClient - how to log sucessfull and failed response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient

I'm trying to create a REST call using WebClient

```
statusWebClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .bodyValue(createBody(state, number))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .doOnEach(response -> log.debug("Notification was sent to {}, response {}", url, response.get()))
                .doOnError(exception -> log.warn("Failed to send notification to {}, cause {}", url, exception.getMessage()))
                .subscribe();
```

I only want to log the call result. On success - log successful message with response body, on 5XX or timeout or other - log the error message. The log should be created in the background (not by the thread that created the call)
But `doOnEach` is executed each time, `doOnError` works fine, but there is also

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from POST
```

logged in the logfile.

I've I also seen in few tutorials `onSuccess` method, but in my setup there is such method.

How can I log success and fail messages?

Comment: You can log in .doOnComplete() method when it is successfull or not

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez `.doOnComplete()` requires Runnable as a parameter - there is no way to get the response

Answer (score 2):

You could setup custom filters for the `WebClient`

```
WebClient.builder()
    .filter(logRequest())
    .filter(logResponse());


private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return (clientRequest, next) -> {
        log.debug("Request: {} {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
        return next.exchange(clientRequest);
    };
}

private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
        log.debug("Response Status: {}", clientResponse.statusCode());
        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not meet requirements "On success - log successful message _with response body_"

Answer (score 1):

This is what I created. Seems that works fine

```
statusWebClient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .bodyValue(createTerminalStatusBody(state, msisdn))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnSuccess(response -> log.debug("Notification was sent to {}, response {}", url, response))
                .doOnError(exception -> log.warn("Failed to send notification to {}, cause {}", url, exception.getMessage()))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty())
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: doOnSuccess() does not seem to exist.